# If a probability density can be written as a product of two variables, are those variables independent?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n\to[0,\infty)$ is a probability density on $\mathbb R^n$. Let $t=t(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $u=u(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ be some functions of $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

If $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = g(t)h(u)$, then are $T=t(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ and $U=u(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ independent? (Assuming $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are distributed according to the distribution defined by $f$)

This question is inspired by another question, where you have the density of $X$ and $Y$ iid $N(0,1)$ variables with density $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-r^2/2}$ where $r^2 = x^2+y^2$. I wanted to immmediately conclude that $R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$ is independent of $\theta = \text{angle of }(X,Y)$, without computing the joint density of $(R=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2},\Theta)$.

Comment: Is $h(\theta)$ supposed to be $1$ in your example? If so, $g$ and $h$ are not the probability densities of $T$ and $U$, as $1$ is not a probability density.

Comment: Yes, $h(\theta)=1$ in my example. That is fine; I am not claiming that $g(t)$ and $h(u)$ are probability densities for $T$ and $U$ (in fact I feel like that would almost make my claim trivial, as then it seems $g(t)h(u)$ would be the joint density whereupon obviously $T$ and $U$ are independent).

The fact remains that the density I wrote can be expressed as $f(r)g(\theta)$, and $R$ and $\Theta$ are independent. So it's not a counterexample.

Comment: Let's take a special case when $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto (r,\theta)$ is a change of coordinates. You want to split the integral $\iint fdx_1dx_2$ over $r\leq R$, $\theta\leq\Theta$ to prove independence. So you switch to the new coordinates and get $\iint f(r,\theta) J(r,\theta)dr d\theta$. It helps that $f$ splits, but unless the Jacobian also splits the integral does not. It *does* split for polar coordinates in your example, but not in general.

Comment: @Conifold Specifically, $f_{R,\Theta}(r,\theta)=f_{X,Y}(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))\,\lVert J_{r,\theta}x((r,\theta),y(r,\theta))\rVert $  . If this function can be expressed as a product of *monovariate* functions of $r$ and $\theta$ **and** has a support whose boundaries (if any) are parallel to the variables' axis, then the random variables will be independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp if the function can be expressed as a product of monovariate functions of $r$ and $\theta$ then its support will be parallel to the variables' axes?

Comment: Not necessarily.  $8xy\,\mathbf 1_{0<x<y<1}$ is a joint probability density function for variables that are not independent... because its support has a boundary that is oblique to both axis.  (The hypotenuse  of the triangle) @ffffffyyyy

Comment: The function $1_{0<x<y<1}$ cannot be written as a product of a function of $x$ and a function of $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have come up with a counterexample to my own question: let $h(u)=1$.